# Error with subscribe or inserting data between ionic and php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, angular, ionic-framework, subscribe

In the file "cargar-obra.page.ts" I have this function:

```
btnClickAgregarObra(){
  const datosObra = {
      num_obra: this.num_obra,
      nombre_obra: this.nombre_obra,
      dir_obra: this.dir_obra,
      muni_obra: this.muni_obra,
      costo_obra: this.costo_obra,
      fecha_ini_obra: this.fecha_ini_obra,
    }
  this.configService.cargarObra(datosObra).subscribe(res=>console.log(res));
```

that last line calls this code on "config.service.ts":

```
public cargarObra(obraData){
    console.log(obraData);
    return this.http.post('http://localhost/obras.php',obraData,{headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'}})
  }
```

About that las code, I put the "console.log(obraData)" to see if the json brings the data correctly, and it does.

And the code above calls the las file "obras.php":

```
$body = file_get_contents("php://input");
$body2 = json_decode($body, true);

$num_obra = $body2['num_obra'];  
$nombre_obra = $body2['nombre_obra'];
$dir_obra = $body2['dir_obra'];  
$muni_obra = $body2['muni_obra']; 
$costo_obra = $body2['costo_obra']; 
$fecha_ini_obra = $body2['fecha_ini_obra']; 
$inspector_asignado = $body2['inspector_asignado']; 

$sql = "INSERT INTO `obra`(`idobra`, `idusuario`, `descripcion`, `direccion`, `localidad`, `fechainicio`, `costo`) VALUES ($num_obra, $inspector_asignado,'$nombre_obra','$dir_obra','$muni_obra','$fecha_ini_obra', $costo_obra)";

$q = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
die();
```

What could be happening? Thanks to all help.

Comment: What kind of error do you get ? ( If you get an error of course...), If you get an error, could you put a screenshot to the error ? or just by editing your question ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the way:

cargar-obra.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ConfigService } from '../config/config.service';
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cargar-obra',
  templateUrl: './cargar-obra.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cargar-obra.page.scss'],
})
export class CargarObraPage implements OnInit {
  num_obra: string = "";
  nombre_obra: string = "";
  dir_obra: string = "";
  muni_obra: string = "";
  costo_obra: string = "";
  fecha_ini_obra: string= "";
  inspector_asignado: string="";
  
  constructor(public configService: ConfigService, public formBuilder: FormBuilder, public alertController: AlertController ) { }

  ngOnInit(){  }
    
  btnClickAgregarObra(){
  const datosObra = {
      num_obra: this.num_obra,
      nombre_obra: this.nombre_obra,
      dir_obra: this.dir_obra,
      muni_obra: this.muni_obra,
      costo_obra: this.costo_obra,
      fecha_ini_obra: this.fecha_ini_obra,
      inspector_asignado: this.inspector_asignado,
    }
  this.configService.cargarObra(datosObra).subscribe(res=>console.log(res));
  } 
}
```

config.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, Subscriber, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConfigService {
  obraData:any;
  inspectoresData:any;
  tipo_user: any;
  public user: any;
  usuario: string;
  password: string;
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }

  //cargar obra nueva
  public cargarObra(obraData){
    console.log(obraData);
    return this.http.post('http://localhost/obras.php',obraData,{headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'}})
  }

  public login (user, pass){
    this.usuario = user;
    
    const login_user = {
      user: user,
      password: pass,
    }
    return this.http.post('http://localhost/login.php',login_user,{headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'}})
  }

  public getUser(){
    return this.usuario;
  }

  public ingresar(tipo_user){
    console.log("funcion ingresar del config service");
    console.log(tipo_user);
    return this.http.post('http://localhost/usuarios.php',tipo_user,{headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'}}).subscribe(res=>{console.log("este "+res);this.user= res}, ()=>{}, ()=>{this.router.navigateByUrl('/home') });
  }
}
```